# Google Map API for Searching Showrooms

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on using the Google Maps API to find showrooms (for example, Audi car) at a particular location.

I tried the Google Maps Places API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters`

but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the following parameters: `"output"` and `"parameters"`

```
output = {json, xml}

parameters = {location, radius, types, language, name, sensor, key}
```

Refer to the documentations for details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/